# How to set forecolor in TemplateField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, templatefield

The code below displays either "M" or "F" in the GridView column after evaluating Gender.

> ```
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <%# Eval("Gender") %>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
> ```

When it's "M" I want to use textcolor red and blue otherwise. How do I do this? Either in the aspx file or in code behind is fine. I'd like to know both ways of doing so if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it via markup you'll have to wrap item template content into e.g. `<div>`, and apply the necessary styles to it like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style='color: <%# Eval("Gender") == "M" ? "Red" : "Blue" %>'>
            <%# Eval("Gender") %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  the `onRowDataBound` event on the GridView to check the 'M' or "F' and then change the fontcolour depending on the value.

```
void gridview_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
string theValue = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

if (theValue ="M")
{
e.Row.Cells[1].Forecolor= Color.Red
}

else if (theValue ="F")
{
e.Row.Cells[1].Forecolor= Color.Blue;
}
}
}
```